# Book where an ancient space ship run by an AI was discovered

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, artificial-intelligence, ftl-drive

I read a book once where humans discovered an ancient space ship. The spaceship was run by a very advanced AI. To travel to distant places, it froze all the humans in place and disconnected itself from space-time.  As a result, it would spend hundreds of thousands of years travelling to another system while no time passed.  In fact, it would sometimes arrive slightly before it left.

I also remember that it included a woman that was going through some strange transformation and evolving beyond humanity.

EDIT: They left Earth in the space ship. I think the spaceship was actually discovered on Earth, but I'm not 100% certain.

The woman that was transforming was referred to as either princess or queen I think. (Priestess maybe?)

I'm pretty sure civilization on Earth was falling apart. Possibly from a major war about to break out.

Also, the ship was huge. A large dome covered a huge garden area which was mainly just the recreation area. It was an entire city in a spaceship.

I vaguely recall something about gold or amber related to the suspension of humans for the long journey outside of spacetime.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might be able to improve this question by checking out the [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [edit]ing in any additional details you remember.

Comment: Possibly Frank Herbert's Destination:Void/Pandora/WorShip sequence?

Comment: I don't think so because this story was about a spaceship and AI that was definitely not made by humans. I was alien and very ancient. Pre-dating humanity I believe.